# IOS NSString Memory Leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

Hi I am having trouble figuring out the cause of a memory leak and I'am starting to wonder if maybe its some sort of IOS bug? The leak appears almost randomly and the stack trace for the leak within the debugger tool shows no methods that I have physically coded? The leaks instrument screen shot is below! Thanks!

[image: Instruments screenshot]

Here's the first possible culprit!

```
#import "BreakfastViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"
#import "Recipe.h"
#import "RecipeAzure.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface BreakfastViewController ()

@end

@implementation BreakfastViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    _tv.dataSource = self;
    _tv.delegate = self;
    _ai = [[AzureInteraction alloc] initAzureInteraction];
    _ai.delegate = self;
    _searchBar.delegate = self;

    self.ai.busyUpdate = ^(BOOL busy)
    {
        if (busy)
        {

        } else
        {

        }
    };

    [_ai getBreakfasts:nil];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)update
{


}
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self resignFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
    {
        [_ai getBreakfasts:nil];


        NSLog(@"SHAKE");
    }
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"breakfast sections   %d",[_ai breakfastCount]);
   NSInteger c = [_ai breakfastCount];
    return c;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      NSLog(@"breakfast sections   %d",[_ai breakfastCount]);
    RecipeAzure *r = [_ai getBreakfastAtIndex:indexPath];
    CustomCell *c = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [c.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    if(r.img64 != nil)
    {
        NSString *str = r.img64;
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:str options:0];

        c.RecipeImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }
    c.RecipeTitle.text = r.title;
    c.IngrediantsLabel.text = r.ingrediants;
    return c;
}

-(void)userFinished:(NSString*)title:(NSString*)ingrediants:(NSString*)method:(NSString*)password:
(NSString*)image
{
    RecipeAzure *createdRecipe = [[RecipeAzure alloc]init];

    createdRecipe.title = title;
    createdRecipe.ingrediants = ingrediants;
    createdRecipe.method = method;
    createdRecipe.password = password;
    createdRecipe.img64 = image;
    createdRecipe.type = @"breakfast";
    NSLog(@"GT HERE");
    [_ai uploadRecipe:createdRecipe];

}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"createBreakfast"])
    {

        CreateRecipeViewController *crvc = [segue destinationViewController];


        crvc.delegate = self;
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailbreakfast"])
    {

        DetailViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *ind = [_tv indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSLog(@"%@",[_ai getBreakfastAtIndex:ind]);
        [dvc setRecipe:[_ai getBreakfastAtIndex:ind]];
        [dvc setDelegate:self];
    }
}
-(void)updateTableview
{
    [_tv reloadData];
}
-(void)setEditChanges:(RecipeAzure *)recipe
{
    NSLog(@"OH MY GOOD %@",recipe.rid);

   [_ai updateRecipe:recipe];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSLog(@"SEARCH BEEN PRESSED");
    [_ai getBreakfasts:searchBar.text];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar
{
    [_ai getBreakfasts:nil];
    searchBar.text = @"";
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

And here's the second possible culprit!

```
#import "CreateRecipeViewController.h"
#import "Recipe.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "BreakfastViewController.h"

@interface CreateRecipeViewController ()
{
    float textViewY;
    //NSString *uepassword;
}

@end

@implementation CreateRecipeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    _Title.delegate = self;
    _Recipe.delegate = self;
    _Ingrediants.delegate = self;
    _Recipe.text = @"Enter Recipe Here...";

    _FinishedEditing.hidden = YES;
    [self.Image setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    if(_delegate == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"WTF");
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textField
{

    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.text = @"";


}
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    textView.text = @"";
     textViewY = textView.frame.origin.y;

    //If we begin editing on the text field we need to move it up to make sure we can still
    //see it when the keyboard is visible.
    //
    //I am adding an animation to make this look better
    if(textView == _Recipe)
    {
        _Title.hidden = YES;
        _Ingrediants.hidden = YES;
        _Image.hidden = YES;
        _AddImage.hidden = YES;
        _FinishedEditing.hidden = NO;


    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Animate Text Field Up" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

        textViewY = _RecipeView.frame.origin.y;


    _RecipeView.frame = CGRectMake(_RecipeView.frame.origin.x,
                               80 , //this is just a number to put it above the keyboard
                               _RecipeView.frame.size.width,
                               _RecipeView.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];



}
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}




- (IBAction)finishedPressed:(id)sender {

      [_Recipe resignFirstResponder];

           [UIView beginAnimations:@"Animate Text Field Up" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

        _RecipeView.frame = CGRectMake(_RecipeView.frame.origin.x,
                                       textViewY ,
                                       _RecipeView.frame.size.width,
                                       _RecipeView.frame.size.height);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        _Title.hidden = NO;
        _Ingrediants.hidden = NO;
        _Image.hidden = NO;
        _AddImage.hidden = NO;
}

- (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];



}

- (IBAction)resignKeyboard:(id)sender {

    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"HELLLOOO");



    UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"Password" message:@"Enter a password to be able to edit this recipe in the future!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Enter"];
    [alert show];





   // uepassword = nil;

    _FinishedEditing.hidden = true;
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        UITextField *password = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        //uepassword = password.text;

        //self.createdRecipe.title = _Title.text;
        //self.createdRecipe.ingrediants = _Ingrediants.text;
        //self.createdRecipe.method = _Recipe.text;
        //self.createdRecipe.img64 = _imagestring;
        //NSString *imageString;
        //if(_Image.image != nil)
        //{
          //  NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_Image.image);
            //imageString = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
        //}

       // [self.delegate userFinished:_Title.text :_Ingrediants.text :_Recipe.text :@"password" :imageString];

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"back" sender:self];



    }
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.Image.image = image;





    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}



@end
```

AzureInteraction class

```
#import "AzureInteraction.h"
#import "Recipe.h"
#import "RecipeAzure.h"


@implementation AzureInteraction
{

}




-(id)initAzureInteraction
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {





        self.client = [client clientWithFilter:self];
         self.table = [_client tableWithName:@"Recipe"];

         self.busyCount = 0;





        return self;

    }
    return nil;
}



-(NSMutableArray*)getBreakfasts:(NSString*)pred
{
    NSLog(@"yeah its doing this but ");

    NSPredicate *bpred;
   if(pred == nil)
   {

     bpred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == 'breakfast'"];
   }
   else{

        bpred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == 'breakfast' AND title == %@",pred];
   }


    [_table readWithPredicate:bpred completion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {


        _breakfasts = [items mutableCopy];


        [_delegate updateTableview];

    }];

    return _breakfasts;





}
-(NSMutableArray*)getLunches:(NSString*)pred
{
    NSLog(@"yeah its doing this but ");
    NSLog(@"%@",_recipes);

    NSPredicate *bpred;
    if(pred == nil)
    {
    bpred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == 'lunch'"];
    }
    else{
        bpred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == 'lunch' AND title == %@",pred];
    }


    [_table readWithPredicate:bpred completion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {


        _lunches = [items mutableCopy];


        [_delegate updateTableview];

    }];

    return _lunches;


}
-(NSMutableArray*)getDinners:(NSString*)pred
{
    NSLog(@"yeah its doing this but ");
    NSLog(@"%@",_recipes);
    NSPredicate *bpred;
    if(pred == nil)
    {
     bpred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == 'dinner'"];
    }
    else{
        bpred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == 'dinner' AND title == %@",pred];
    }


    [_table readWithPredicate:bpred completion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {


        _dinners = [items mutableCopy];


        [_delegate updateTableview];

    }];

    return _dinners;


}
-(void)updateTable
{






}
- (void)busy:(BOOL)busy
{
    // assumes always executes on UI thread
    if (busy)
    {
        if (self.busyCount == 0 && self.busyUpdate != nil)
        {
            self.busyUpdate(YES);
        }
        self.busyCount ++;
    }
    else
    {
        if (self.busyCount == 1 && self.busyUpdate != nil)
        {
            self.busyUpdate(FALSE);
        }
        self.busyCount--;
    }
}

- (void)handleRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                 next:(MSFilterNextBlock)next
             response:(MSFilterResponseBlock)response
{
    // A wrapped response block that decrements the busy counter
    MSFilterResponseBlock wrappedResponse = ^(NSHTTPURLResponse *innerResponse, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
        [self busy:NO];
        NSLog(@"OK");

        response(innerResponse, data, error);
    };

    // Increment the busy counter before sending the request
    [self busy:YES];
    NSLog(@"HMM");
    next(request, wrappedResponse);
}

-(RecipeAzure*)getBreakfastAtIndex:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *d = [_breakfasts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    RecipeAzure* t = [[RecipeAzure alloc] init];

    t.rid = [d valueForKey:@"id"];

    t.title = [d valueForKey:@"title"];
    t.ingrediants = [d valueForKey:@"ingrediants"];
    t.method = [d valueForKey:@"method"];
    t.type = [d valueForKey:@"type"];
    t.img64 = [d valueForKey:@"imageencoded"];
    t.password = [d valueForKey:@"password"];


    return t;
}
-(RecipeAzure*)getLunchAtIndex:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *d = [_lunches objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    RecipeAzure* t = [[RecipeAzure alloc] init];
    t.rid = [d valueForKey:@"id"];
    t.title = [d valueForKey:@"title"];
    t.ingrediants = [d valueForKey:@"ingrediants"];
    t.method = [d valueForKey:@"method"];
    t.img64 = [ d valueForKey:@"imageencoded"];
    t.password = [d valueForKey:@"password"];

    return t;
}
-(RecipeAzure*)getDinnerAtIndex:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *d = [_dinners objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    RecipeAzure* t = [[RecipeAzure alloc] init];
    t.rid = [d valueForKey:@"id"];
    t.title = [d valueForKey:@"title"];
    t.ingrediants = [d valueForKey:@"ingrediants"];
    t.method = [d valueForKey:@"method"];
    t.img64 = [ d valueForKey:@"imageencoded"];
    t.password = [d valueForKey:@"password"];

    return t;
}
-(NSInteger)breakfastCount
{
    NSLog(@"COUNTING");
    return [_breakfasts count];
}
-(NSInteger)lunchCount
{
    return [_lunches count];
}
-(NSInteger)dinnerCount
{
    return [_dinners count];
}
-(void)uploadRecipe:(RecipeAzure*)recipe
{
    NSDictionary *createdDictionary;
    if(recipe.img64 != nil)
    {
   createdDictionary = @{@"imageencoded": recipe.img64,@"ingrediants":recipe.ingrediants,
                               @"method":recipe.method,@"password":recipe.password,@"title":recipe.title,@"type":recipe.type};
   }
    else{
        createdDictionary = @{@"imageencoded": @"no image",@"ingrediants":recipe.ingrediants,@"method":recipe.method,@"password":recipe.password,@"title":recipe.title,@"type":recipe.type};
    }

    [_table insert:createdDictionary completion:^(NSDictionary *insertedItem, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Item inserted, id: %@", [insertedItem objectForKey:@"id"]);
        }
    }];

}

-(void)updateRecipe:(RecipeAzure*)r
{
    NSLog(@"BEFORE AN EXCEPTION");
    NSLog(r.rid);
  NSDictionary *createdDictionary = @{@"id":r.rid,@"imageencoded": r.img64,@"ingrediants":r.ingrediants,
                          @"method":r.method,@"password":r.password,@"title":r.title,@"type":r.type};
    [_table update:createdDictionary completion:^(NSDictionary *item, NSError *error) {
        if(error)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
    }];
}




@end
```

The CustomCell class doesn't really have any logic within it.. So here's the .h file instead!

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *RecipeTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *IngrediantsLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *RecipeImage;

@end
```

Comment: Empty methods, variables with names like `c`, and entire classes like `RecipeAzure` and `CustomCell` that aren't even included in a memory leak question?  Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the formatting! It needs a little doing up I must admit! I shall upload the RecipeAzure and CustomCell classes now!

Comment: Why are you using `_foo` all over the place? You should almost never use `_foo` to access a variable. Use `self.foo` instead

Comment: `_foo` vs. `self.foo` is style. It'll have little to no impact here, unless the property is set as `copy`.

Comment: @Almo The problem really is that I am occasionally finding this memory leak when transitioning from the CreateRecipeViewController to the BreakfastViewController. It doesn't happen all the time only occasionally strangely!

Comment: @StevenFisher it's not style, it's safer. Most modern languages do not even allow low level access like `_foo` to instance variables specifically to avoid problems like this. It probably isn't the cause but it could be. I would start by changing all `_foo` code to `self.foo` and re-test for leaks.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert is absolutely correct. Using the accessor methods is the preferred way to go, rather than directly accessing the instance variable that backs it. When you directly access that instance variable, you lose a lot of things - KVO, correct memory management, and more. This is especially important under ARC. This is covered in "Programming with Objective-C: Encapsulating Data". Specifically, sentences like "It’s best practice to use a property on an object any time you need to keep track of a value or another object." should stand out.

Comment: There is a use of `_delegate` in a completion block -- which will retain the delegate.  `self.delegate` retains `self`.

Comment: Note, quelfish, "on **another** object." Self is not another object.

Comment: @StevenFisher -- that is pretty clearly *not* what the Apple document is recommending.  It's advocating the use of KVC so that other things can be built on that foundation.  If the instance methods of the class dick with the iVars in base c behind the back of KVC, you break KVO.

Comment: Absolutely you can break KVO, and if a class exposes properties publicly with the intent that they be observable (or, for that matter, able to be overridden), you shouldn't set fields directly. However, problems come most often not when you don't follow a specific pattern, but when you don't understand why things work the way they work. `self.value` vs. `_value` is unrelated to finding a memory leak (though it may change the symptoms if value is set to copy). So I think in this specific case the advice to change `_value` to `self.value` to solve the problem is poor.

Comment: Well, I do think it's interesting to ponder whether using `self.delegate` vs. `_delegate` in a block is the incrementing the retain count on self in one and delegate in the other...  though he's leaking a string, so you're right that it's moot.

Comment: To get back to the original question, any time you have a memory leak in ARC code there's really only one pattern to follow: 1. Analyze deeply, see what's spotted. 2. Check for simple things, like strong delegates, runtime warnings. Fix those FIRST. 3. Figure out what's *actually* leaking. It's not going to be the compiler. Look for your custom objects or containers first, and try of figure out the parent(s) amongst the other leaks. 4. Think carefully about why the parent(s) would leak. What has a strong reference to it? THEN read your code and see if any of your expectations are violated.

Comment: Btw, @stevesliva, I absolutely agree that _delegate vs. self.delegate *in a block* is interesting. It should absolutely use the weakSelf/strongSelf dance, then use strongSelf.delegate. Otherwise, self (not even _delegate!) is retained by the block. I believe there's a compiler warning for this accidental self access in a block that you should turn on, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're doing here:

```
// A wrapped response block that decrements the busy counter
MSFilterResponseBlock wrappedResponse = ^(NSHTTPURLResponse *innerResponse, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    [self busy:NO];
    NSLog(@"OK");

    response(innerResponse, data, error);
};
```

But use the weakSelf pattern:

Before the block: `__weak AzureInteraction* weakSelf = self;`

And then in the block: `[weakSelf busy:NO]`

Blocks that invoke `self` will retain self unless the reference is explicitly weak.

Also, your use of `_delegate` in a block is equally scary.  Though that block likely completes more synchronously than this one.

I'm scrutinizing your blocks because of the stack trace, but it could be another that you don't show here given that it's something about pixel rendition.   Regardless, you need to be aware that these blocks you are invoking will retain pointers to the objects within them.

Comment: Hey thanks for giving it a look! I commented all the azureinteraction code out and the leak still occurs! But I will definitely take your advice on the blocks! Could the setsharedblocks be related to the uiimage within the create recipe class?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how, but that doesn't mean it's not.  The stack also mentions a string *copy*, so I'd look for that in your blocks. I'm not clear on how a copy made in a block would necessarily not be released later if you're assigning it to an iVar, though.

Comment: The most obvious answer is that the parent might not be released. We're seeing in the screenshot leaks of a particular backtrace, but (unless I'm misreading the screenshot?) that doesn't mean there aren't other leaks. Chase custom classes/containers FIRST, only chase strings after. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the problem but I suggest doing a bunch of code cleanup. You have a whole lot of weird stuff going on like this:

```
NSPredicate *bpred;
if(pred == nil)
{
  bpred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == 'lunch'"];
}
else{
  bpred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == 'lunch' AND title == %@",pred];
}
```

How can it ever not be nil?

And this, which does nothing at all:

```
self.ai.busyUpdate = ^(BOOL busy)
{
    if (busy)
    {

    } else
    {

    }
};
```

I would commit to version control (you're using version control right?) and delete/fix all of that stuff. Then see if the leak is still there.

If the leak is still there, perhaps start deleting big chunks of code just to find out where the leak is. Then once you've narrowed the problem down you should be able to find the issue and restore all your deleted code from version control.

It's extremely unlikely to be a bug in iOS. The NSString class was created in the early 1980's and hasn't changed much since, any bugs were fixed a long long time ago.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look through it a bit! Appreciate it! Yeah I will begin refactoring the code a lot now! I've commented out all of the code within the CreateRecipe class and haven't seen the memory leak since! So I shall hopefully begin narrowing down the problem! Right ok! I was expecting it to be some sort of error by me but I was finding it strange that the leak tool was not pointing out any of my code! Thanks for the advice anyway :)

Comment: @bdavies6086 because of technical details of how Obj-C works, it's very difficult to programatically determine where the leak occurs. It can find some types of leak, but not all. Did you try the "Analyze" feature by the way? It can find some leaks - but will also false positive.

Comment: Right! I have not no! I will have to look into that! I have just uncommented the area within the CreateRecipe class where Strings are passed back to the delegate which is the breakfastviewcontroller and a memory leak popped up! So I will have to look into this a bit!